# Couple pyplot array of AxesSubplots to a figure object

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame and I'm using the df.plot function to make a panel of subplots.

Something like this:

```
x = np.random.randn(50)
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': x, '2': x, '3': x, '4':x})

ax_lst = df.plot(subplots = True, layout = (2,2))
```

The df.plot function returns a numpy array of AxesSubplots. How can I couple this to a figure object so that I can change figure-level attributes?

I have tried with this but it didn't work:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.axes.append(ax_lst)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `Axes`object has a [`get_figure`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_figure.html) method. In your case,

```
fig = ax_lst[0].get_figure()
```

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Use something like this

```
ax_lst = df['1'].plot(color='green', linewidth=2.0)
ax_lst1 = df['2'].plot(color='blue',linestyle=':')
.
.
```

You can modify any ploty in certain limits of `df.plot()`

Or you can use subplots.
[See the documentation for more details](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html)